How to set up an online one-to-many "tournament"?
My children are far away and I had the idea to set up an online "tournament" between us as a bonding activity (we are complete amateurs)
I am looking for a way to have three simultaneous games where everyone will play against the two others.
I had a look at lichess but I did not find such a feature and I would prefer to keep it simple and not to have to create 6 accounts.
Is there a way to set this up?

Note: I am well aware that this is not a good way to play proper chess but this is really for the fun and the opportunity to be (virtually) together.

On the sites I know I don't see how to do it without one account per player, and to be honest I don't really understand the objection. If you are willing to break that restriction on Lichess at least create a team, get the family to sign up to the team, and the it's easy to create tournaments just for that team.

@IanBush my objection you mean? I am not sure you can play two plays at the same time under one account - thus the 6 accounts that would be needed (and the anticheat of lichess would get crazy I guess). I am looking for a simultaneous tournament - if this is possible I will try right away. Thanks!

so just to clarify: everyone does have (or can easily get) one account?

@DM oh yes, everyone has or can easily get an account on whatever system.

If you set your games up to be Correspondence games on lichess or Daily games on chess.com, you can play multiple such games at the same time. There's no reason why you have to wait a day per move; you can move quickly if you wish.
You can also do this with Live games on chess.com, but only if everyone has premium. Lichess has a "simultaneous exhibition" option, but that would only allow one person to play multiple games. So I think the Correspondence/Daily option is the better way to go.
